# jquery val() doesn't change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7n6pysLr/

I'm trying to change the value of the `#test p` from `Hello` to `Bye`. It doesn't work:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="test"><p>Hello</p></div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
   $("#test p").val("Bye");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `<p>` tag doesn't have a `value` attribute because it's not `<input>`

Comment: use html instead of val

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the html in this case with `.html()`

```js
$("#test p").html("Bye");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @parsecer Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
val() method is used for <input>.
In your case you are using <p></p> so here you have to use .html() or .text(), both will work. These methods are used to update the innerText/innerHtml.

html() : returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.
text() : method sets or returns the text content of the selected elements.
```